# How to get a list of active network interfaces in php

Tags: php, sockets, network-programming, php-socket

So What I want is to achieve this through php standalone using socket functions-

```
$  sudo ifconfig | cut -d " " -f1 | awk 'NF==1{print $1}'
 eth0
 lo
 wlan0
```

I know I can do so by using `system` command but for that either I need to change sticky bit permission on `ifconfig (root privelaged command)` or need to write a C wrapper.

So please tell me the best possible way to achieve this through PHP.

My purpose is to display the available network interfaces list to the front end user using  a application developed using HTML and PHP.

Comment: don't know about other unices, but on my ubuntu box, root privs are NOT required to simply run ifconfig to list interfaces. root's only necessary for changing things.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can add the user your webserver runs as (usually, www or www-data) to `/etc/sudoers`. Then you should be able to access the ifconfig command via a system call. Obviously there is a security impact here. You should restrict the access to the ifconfig command if you take that route.

```
$out = system("sudo ifconfig ...");
```

Answer (score 1):

on a Debian based distributions, You can use this library that I wrote. it can read/write /etc/network/interfaces

https://github.com/carp3/networkinterfaces

```
<?php
//include composer autoloader
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

// 'import' NetworkInterfaces class
use NetworkInterfaces\Adaptor;
use NetworkInterfaces\NetworkInterfaces;

// create new handle from /etc/networking/interfaces
$handle = new NetworkInterfaces('/etc/networking/interfaces');

// parse file
$handle->parse();

// print all adaptors
var_dump($handle->Adaptors);
```